# How do I get a colored object to glow on white?

Tags: emission

Emission works great when the environment is darker, but I'm having trouble getting a colored object to show up on my white surface. I tried lowering the roughness, but that ended up making it look more like a reflection. I know it's not realistic, but it's the effect I'm trying to go for.

This is where I'm at:

[image]

Comment: Are you rendering with Eevee? Emission only casts onto other objects in Cycles, in Eevee you can use something called a Light Probe. If you don't want to use Cycles, I can show you how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Switch the render engine to Cycles and Emission will cast light onto other objects as expected.

[image]

In Eevee, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Add 'Light Probe' >'Irradiance Volume'

[image]

Scale it up so the inner bounding box surrounds the scene.

In Render Settings under 'Indirect Lighting' you'll have to 'Bake Indirect Lighting'

[image]

In this image I've already baked it so you can see the result. Hope that's what you're looking for.